# How to get scale ratio between design window size (in VS forms designer) and real size?

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, size, window-resize

I have a standard WinApi Dialog window, created in form designer of Visual Studio. Design size is eg. 500x600 in pixels. But if I run application and get size of window (GetWindowSize()), the size is different, almost bigger, dependent of the monitor resolution.

According to this ratio I must adjust also font size, and child window possition and size...
Where I get this ratio?

Thank for help.
Majkl

Comment: "GetWindowSize" isn't a Windows API.

Comment: Probably your DPI setting is 125% or higher. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Comment: Hard to give any help here, seeing as there is virtually no useful information. There's no information what type of resource you are editing, there's no information how you are measuring the window/client size at runtime, and no information on your system's settings. Please update the question to include the required information, and ideally a [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry, I thought GetWindowRect().

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation **[DIALOG Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/dialog-resource#remarks)** and **[GetDialogBaseUnits Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdialogbaseunits#remarks)**, The size value in the dialog resource is the dialog unit. **The unit of this size is not pixels but DLU (dialog logical units), which is a coordinate unit that has nothing to do with resolution.** The conversion relationship between it and pixels is related to the current dialog font. Not pixels, to convert to pixels, you can use [MapDialogRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapdialogrect) to convert.

> Each horizontal base unit is equal to 4 horizontal dialog template units; each vertical base unit is equal to 8 vertical dialog template units. Therefore, to convert dialog template units to pixels, use the following formulas:
>
> ```cpp
> pixelX = MulDiv(templateunitX, baseunitX, 4);
> pixelY = MulDiv(templateunitY, baseunitY, 8);
> ```
>
> Similarly, to convert from pixels to dialog template units, use the following formulas:
>
> ```cpp
> templateunitX = MulDiv(pixelX, 4, baseunitX);
> templateunitY = MulDiv(pixelY, 8, baseunitY);
> ```

You can press **"CTRL+T"** to preview the actual size of the window in VS forms designer.